# Electric furnace wiring

Tags: electrical, furnace, electrical-panel

[image: furnace connection]

I am wiring a 240v furnace with 6/3 wire. The furnace has individual breakers as the connection point, one for each phase.
My question is- is it ok to jumper the neutral from one breaker to the other. Is it even necessary since the phases us each other to complete the circuit? Any safety issues?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I gather you yourself did not put the blue dots on the wires, and this is how the furnace is factory wired??

Comment: Correct. I have done nothing but removed the panel to expose the wiring pictured. The blue dots are on the furnace side of the breakers.

Comment: Does your furnace say that it requires neutral?

Comment: What make/model is your furnace?

Comment: It is a Revolv XLO375-B ? Not sure all the specs or if thats the model number. I bought it six months ago and then I knew everything. And of course the book is for 4 different models.

Comment: Try RE9-023 aka https://www.acdirect.com/system-components/mobile-home-units/mobile-home-electric-furnace/revolv-23kw-downflow-electric-furnace-with-coil-cabinet ... yes, its specs call out 240V.  Not 120/240V.   You don't need /3 cable, /2 will suffice.  There is no legal way to make use of the extra neutral wire, just cap it off at both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You furnace looks like it is an approximately 20-KW model.  It requires no neutral.  It is not asking for a neutral.  It requires A phase and B phase from a single phase residential service.  And the wiring layout will be as follows: from the top, first breaker, A phase on top and B phase on bottom, and Second breaker A-phase on top and B-phase on bottom. You will need two runs of 6-2 copper or two runs of two 4awg aluminum with ground.  In the house panel you will need two each new 60-Amp breakers.

Comment: Is 6 alum good to 60, or does OP need 4 if he chooses aluminum?

Comment: @Tyson -- yeah, he'll need to go to 4AWG for Al wire

Comment: That's what I thought to.